# Leaflet and D3js: Feature.properties are not showing in Leaflet popup

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

**How do you add feature properties under a D3 chart in a Leafletjs popup?**

I got the popup and chart working, but I can't seem to add the feature.properties below the chart.

> Here's a sample of my geoJSON data:

```
var myData = [{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"Gulran","Province":"Hirat","Ethnic1":0.19,"Ethnic2":0.32,"Ethnic3":"0.10","Ethnic4":"0.00","Ethnic5":"0.10","Ethnic6":"0.00"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[60.941162109375,29.897805610155874],[61.92993164062499,31.034108344903512],[63.34716796874999,31.3348710339506],[64.05029296875,30.401306519203583],[64.412841796875,29.735762444449076],[64.09423828125,29.36302703778376],[62.29248046875,29.36302703778376],[60.941162109375,29.897805610155874]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"Name":"Chahar Burjak","Province":"Nimroz","Ethnic1":0.25,"Ethnic2":0.12,"Ethnic3":0.03,"Ethnic4":0.01,"Ethnic5":"0.00","Ethnic6":"0.00"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[63.38012695312499,31.3348710339506],[65.06103515625,31.80289258670676],[65.6982421875,31.156408414557],[66.016845703125,30.467614102257855],[65.291748046875,30.164126343161097],[64.22607421875,30.0405664305846],[63.38012695312499,31.3348710339506]]]}}]}];
```

> Here's my popup code:

```
var popup = L.popup({minWidth: 600}).setContent(div);
        layer.bindPopup(popup + '<br>' + feature.properties.NAME);
```

Here's my [**jsfiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/quro9bon/3/) to test. As you can see, the popups are working, but can't get the feature properties to display under the chart.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing multiple possible issues.

You are opening a `<svg>` element, but you are not closing it. If you add text like this it will get "swallowed" and end up within the rendered `<svg>here</svg>`, but the chart drawn by d3 will hide it:

```
// won't show the text
var div = $('<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"><svg>here is some text</div>')[0];
```

You can fix that by using a self-closing `<svg/>`:

```
var div = $('<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"><svg/><br/>here is some text</div>')[0];
```

Next issue is that you are trying to combine a `L.popup` object with strings:

```
layer.bindPopup(popup + 'here is some text');
```

Because this `L.popup` is an object you can not simply concatenate text to it. The result would look like this: `"[object Object]here is some text"`.

And then you are using `feature.properties.NAME` which will not work because your GeoJSON properties' keys are named `Name` (notice the capitalization) - use instead: `feature.properties.Name`

---

To conclude, to solve your problem change the one line `var div = ...`  in your `onEachFeature_LMA` function to this:

```
var div = $('<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"><svg/><br/>'+feature.properties.Name+'</div>')[0];
```

---

Since you are using jQuery, if you want to add more graphs, other HTML elements later you can also build the popup's HTML like this:

```
  var div = $('<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"><svg/></div>')[0];
  var div2 = $('<div></div>').html(feature.properties.Name);
  $(div).append($(div2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will take a look. However, as for the SVG element...there is a SVG closing tag if you inspect the code in a browser inspector. Is that not the case?

Comment: @redshift Yes and no.. [browsers auto-complete missing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26850313/1781026), maybe even the d3 library does this, I'm not sure. So when using the 'inspect' function you'll see the browser's interpreted or fixed version of your code, it's not necessarily the source code you initally wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working in my jsfiddle! However, on my website I get an "undefined" text under the bar chart. The code looks the same on both sites, so I'll have to troubleshoot. Do you spot anything?: http://ogmda.com/sandbox/map.html

Comment: @redshift Take a look at your json file, there is no "Name" attribute,   `{"type":"Feature","properties":{"FID":1,"OBJECTID":135,"PROV_34_NA":"Nangarhar","DIST_34_NA":"Deh Bala","DISTID":808,"PROVID":8}` -- use `feature.properties.PROV_34_NA` or `feature.properties.DIST_34_NA`:

Comment: I guess my data export got corrupted in the process. Thanks! I'll mark this as solved!