# JS - regexp - open tag vs closed tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to count the number of opening `<tr`s and compare them to the number of closing `/tr>`s to check for template errors in my HTML generation. My code is pretty simple:

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML; //to have it as a string
var trstart_results = (markup.match(/<tr/g) || []).length;
var trend_results = (markup.match(/\/tr>/g) || []).length;
```

Problem is, that I have in HTML code 95x `tr` and 97x `/tr`, but console.log says both are 97x.

Anyone know, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: [TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) ---- don't use regex to parse HTML, if you have opening tags, you surely have closing tags, so just count the elements instead

Comment: Why don't you just traverse the DOM to the tr element, and just take the length of it's outer HTML?

Comment: Well, if the length of the open TR is different from closing TR it means somebody messed up HTML template :-) And that is exactly what is this algo for.

Comment: oh, I understand, I think this is a language based miscommunication

Comment: If my edit clarification is correct, this is actually a fine use of regex in regards to markup language, OP isn't trying to parse arbitrary ml, just count occurrences of a pattern.

Comment: OP, what do you mean by html code? Can you reproduce this bug with a table with 3 rows? Or provide an example giving a result which is incorrect in your opinion?

Comment: Exactly as @WillBarnwell said - I am trying to get real count of "TR" and real count of "/TR"... If tr - /tr does not match, there is a problem in the code and needs to be solved.

Comment: Please provide some html which gives incorrect results

Comment: But you're using `innerHTML`, if the HTML isn't valid, and there's missing closing tags, it's a bit late to start validating and editing with clientside code.

Comment: without the html content, it is very hard to predict what's the issue. Your regex looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine,  but browser inserted missing html tags. Look at this question from stack:

[Do browsers automatically insert missing HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850250/do-browsers-automatically-insert-missing-html-tags/26850313)

Answer (score 0):

I made a library that does something like this. I was dealing with badly formatted HTML that even html parsers couldn't properly handle. But some tags were always correct.

https://github.com/icodeforlove/balanced.js

```
balanced.matches({
    source: document.documentElement.innerHTML,
    head: /<tr[^>]*>/,
    open: /<tr[^>]*>/,
    close: '</tr>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so after a lot of tries I found finally solution which worked for me :-). First of all, I need to put the whole document as a string. ->

```
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

But this is not enough since the browser corrects your code. So you need to this string split to array. ->

```
html_arr = markup.split(" ");
```

Now we can manipulate all the array without any browser limitation. So my final code is :

```
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
html_arr = markup.split(" ");
var trcounter = 0;
var trendcounter = 0;
for (i = 0;i<html_arr.length;i++){
    if (html_arr[i].match(/<tr/g)){
        trcounter += 1;
    }else if (html_arr[i].match(/<\/tr>/g)){
        trendcounter += 1;
    }
}
console.log(trcounter);
console.log(trendcounter);
```

This code is wild and working with over 8000 fields in array so in a very big html code it will get like 3 seconds to execute.

Anyway, I am so happy I solved this and also very happy I could share with you results :-)

Best Luck guys!