# Auto close html tags when render in view?

Tags: c#, html, razor

```
<div>some text <b> more text: </div> //is missing </b>
```

The HTML code above I had store in my Database and It is missing  tag.

And when I render this HTML code in view like the code below:

```
var htmlCode = @"<div>some text <b> more text: </div>"; //is missing </b>
@Html.Raw(htmlCode)
```

Because missing  so the result will like code below:

```
<div>some text <b> more text: </div>
<b>my code</b>
<b>some code</b>
<b>......</b>
```

How can I disable browser auto add tag (in my case is auto add `<b></b>` each `div`) or how to I can auto self-closing tags by C#.

Comment: The browser is going to make its best effort to correct invalid markup.  The best approach would be to correct your markup instead of relying on the browser's guess.

Comment: Perhaps the following post can help you to at least partially automate a little fixing of your markup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661640/how-to-fix-ill-formed-html-with-html-agility-pack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do browsers automatically insert missing HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850250/do-browsers-automatically-insert-missing-html-tags)