# Browser's html source code differs from python requests result

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

The html source code I see in the browser differs from the html code i receive when using python's requests.get.
Image in the link below.
In the browser

and  are siblings, with requests  is a child of

Any idea anybody?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoSjR.png

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Browser try to fix unclosed tags, in this case the `<p>`.

It closes it before the `<h5>` heading since headings are usually outside paragraphs.

For more info see [Do browsers automatically insert missing HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850250/do-browsers-automatically-insert-missing-html-tags)

Comment: Thank you so much!
I solved the problem by using a different parser ("html5lib" instead of "html.parser") in BeautifulSoup, html5lib auto-closes just like my browser does.