# Using Jquery, how to break a node into smaller nodes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My program should do the following when any one of the buttons are clicked:

1. Split the 'tbody' node into two 'tbody' nodes. For instance, if you pressed the second button, the first two rows will be the children of one 'tbody' node and the other rows will be the children of another 'tbody' node.
2. Create a new 'tbody' node right in between those two 'tbody' nodes.
3. The innerHTML of the new 'tbody' node should be

```
<tr><td><p> Clicked </p></td></tr>
```

So if you click the second button, the desired html would be

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><p> Clicked </p></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button> Split </button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, my javascript program fails to do this.
This is my javascript code.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var currentRow = $(this).parent().parent();
  var htmlStr =     "</tbody>";
  htmlStr +=        "<tbody>";
  htmlStr +=          "<tr><td><p>Clicked</p></td></tr>";
  htmlStr +=        "</tbody>";
  htmlStr +=        "<tbody>";
  currentRow.after(htmlStr);
  console.log($("table").html());
});
```

You can go to this JsFiddle link to test out my code and see what it ends up doing. Also, the last line of my code doesn't print out html neatly. If you know how to make it print it in a better way, please let me know.

https://jsfiddle.net/kjvpruse/14/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is that you're building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate HTML with [partial or invalid HTML strings](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser). Any start tag will be completed automatically by the browser when you append it.

---

This was not trivial but works as expected

```js
$(function() {
  const $table = $("table"); // can be more specific using an ID
  $table.on("click", "button", function() { // delegate to keep the event handler
    const $currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    const $currentTBody = $(this).closest("tbody");

    // All the rows before the clicked row
    const $prevRows = $currentRow.prevAll(); // may be empty
    // All the rows after the clicked row
    const $nextRows = $currentRow.nextAll(); // may be empty

    // Create and append a "Clicked!" row in a new tbody after the body of the clicked row
    const $clickedTBody = $(`<tbody><tr><td><p>Clicked! ${this.id}</p></td></tr></tbody>`); // this is now a jQuery tbody object

    const $newPrevTBody = $prevRows.length > 0 ? $("<tbody></tbody>").append($prevRows) : null; // did we have any or not?
    const $newNextTBody = $nextRows.length > 0 ? $("<tbody></tbody>").append($nextRows) : null;

    // Gather elements in order to insert - remember to handle previously inserted tbodies
    const elementsToInsert = [
      ...$currentTBody.prevAll().get().reverse(), // prevAll are reversed, spreading (...) the reversed array
      $newPrevTBody,
      $clickedTBody,
      $newNextTBody,
      ...$currentTBody.nextAll() // the nextAll is in the right order
    ].filter(Boolean); // Remove any null or undefined elements

    // Clear the table and insert the elements in the correct order
    $table.empty().append(elementsToInsert); // clear the table and append the array of elements in one go

    // Remove the clicked row (not really necessary since we've already emptied the table and re-added rows, but kept for clarity)
    $currentRow.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id='x'> Split </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="x"> Add a new row after this row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id='y'> Split </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="y"> Add a new row after this row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id='z'> Split </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="z"> Add a new row after this row</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess it did answer my question, but this pops up so many other questions. 

"Any start tag will be completed automatically when you append it"
~~  How do we know this or rather, where can I find the information for this? I'm trying to look up what "...$" does, but I can't find it. Could you please link me to a page that explains what it does? I understand $("selector"), but I don't understand what this does $("htmlString"). A link to a doc on this functionality would help me. I notice there is a dollar sign after every variable. Is this to distingush JS variables from jQuery?

Comment: I prefix jQuery with $ (which a lot of ppl using jQuery do). `$("htmlstring")` creates a jQuery object of that html.
Yes there is [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser) here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850250/do-browsers-automatically-insert-missing-html-tags)